# Need a shell script to find the latest file from a directory and move it to another on a weekly basis

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am new to shell scripting and I need some help with it. I have a requirement to move the latest expdp dump file from one directory to another where it will be maintained for 90 days and then deleted. This job should run once a week.

Comment: I use `find ./ -mtime +10 -delete` to delete logs older than 10 days. Maybe you can adapt for `find` for your convenience.

Answer (score 2):

Create a script with something like this;

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "$(ls -t <name of your file> | head -1)" /directory/it/has/to/go
find /directory/it/has/to/go -type f -mtime 90 -exec rm {} +
```

Now we have to create a cronjob so this script runs every week.

```
$: crontab -e
```

Add this line:

```
0 0 * * 0 yourscript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `crontab` to schedule a command. To do that, run `crontab -e` and add something like the following like:

```
0 8 * * Mon  bash -c 'cd /path/to/dir; mv "$(ls -t expdp*.dump | head -1)" /another/dir/'
```

That will look for the latest file that matches `expdp*.dump` in `/path/to/dir`and move it to `/another/dir/`. Scheduled to run 8am, every Monday.

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this (I have no idea if this is the best way to do it as I just put something together and it's working).

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /source/directory/
cp `ls -1t | head -1` /destination/directory/
```

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)